# Autohotkey pressing key in specific window

Tags: autohotkey

I run multiple windows of the same program and I want to make ahk press a specific button in all of them, for examle "0". I tried using alt tab command, it worked but only 1 time and I was not able to loop it properly. Maybe there is another better way to do make it press a key in every window?

Comment: see documentation: `winGet` -> list cmd

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use Internet Explorer and each IE window is separate (not all in different tabs in the same window), the following should show you how to loop through each open IE window.  It will also show explorer windows, so your code can first determine what type of window before proceeding to send the keys.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; approximate match
for x in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows {
    {
         MsgBox,,Open Windows, % "`n" x.locationName "`n`n" x.locationURL "`n`n" x.FullName "`n"
         winactivate, % x.locationName
         sleep, 1000
         WinMaximize, % x.locationName
         sleep, 1000
         ; do something here
    }
}
return
```

Hth,